# If a correspondence has an open graph, then it is lower hemicontinous.

Tags: general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces

The definition of lower hemicontinous I'm working with is the following:

A function $F$ is lower-hemicontinous at $x∈X$ if for any $V⊆Y$ s.t. $F(x)∩V≠∅$  there’s an open $U⊆X$ with $x∈U$ s.t. $F(U)∩V≠∅$.

Also I would like to see an example where the opposite does not hold, that is, a
lower hemicontinuous correspondence whose graph is not open.

Comment: For an example try $x \to [x, +\infty)$ or $x \to (-\infty, x]$; one of them will work IIRC. (from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$ both).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, start with definitions: suppose $\delta(F)=\{(x,y)\in X \times Y\mid y \in F(x)\}$ is an open subset of $X \times Y$.

Let $x \in X$ be arbitrary and $V$ any open subset of $Y$ so that $F(x) \cap V \neq \emptyset$, so we have $y_0 \in F(x)$ so that $y_0 \in V$.

So we know that $(x, y_0) \in \delta(F)$ is a point in the (open!) graph, so by the product topology definition of openness we have some $U_0 \times V_0$ with $x_0 \in U_0, y_0 \in V_0$, $U \subseteq X$ open, $V_0 \subseteq Y$ open with $U_0 \times V_0 \subseteq \delta(F)$.

Can you think what the required $U$ for lower hemicontinuity has to be and show it to be true?

Comment: I don't think so, I'm struggling with topology. However, thank you very much !!